# Keeping files in cache VSCode/Prevent erase after closing

Tags: visual-studio-code, notepad++

I recently moved to VSCode from Notepad++, and I just found an annoying difference.
When I had for example n files opened in Notepad++ and I closed it(also if restarting computer), when re-opening it I used to find those files again, also if they were deleted from folder or edited.

In VSCode, just some files are keeping opened(it depends if you have got them locally or download once and then delete or refresh them), and that's an annoying thing for me.

I guess this function is related to cache system, so I am wondering: Is there any method to make the VSCode cache work like Notepad++'s does in VSCode? Are there any extensions to do it?

I mean: to keep files always in cache, except when I close them.

Thank you in advance